# Jquery fuction on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As you can see in the Snippet code below, I have two buttons and one input for each container. Now, The input **calc and sums up** the number of clicks on the 2 buttons in the **same container**. But, it's only working for the **first container**. How can I make it work for each container **separately** **without setting an ID** for each group of inputs?

```js
$(function() {
 $('.click').on('click', function() {
  $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) + 1);
 });
 $('.click').click(function() {
  var val1 = +$('.val1').val();
  var val2 = +$('.val2').val();
  $('.count').val(val1+val2);
 });
});
```

```css
.cont {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>First</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" class="count" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val1" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val2" value="0">
</div>

<h1>Second</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" class="count" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val1" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val2" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: How about using  seperate classes for each container fields then?

Comment: @BonishKoirala The things is that I want to have like a thousand of different containers, and I want to avoid setting a seperate class to each one..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get the parent of the clicked element, then search for the `.valx` elements only within this parent.

```
$('.click').click(function (e) {
    var $parent = $(e.currentTarget).parent();

    var val1 = +$parent.find('.val1').val();
    var val2 = +$parent.find('.val2').val();
    $parent.find('.count').val(val1 + val2);
});
```

This way, you can have as many counters as you want.

---

**Update:**

You can also add the +1 feature in the same click event. Like so:

```
$('.click').click(function (e) {
    var $input = $(e.currentTarget);
    var $parent = $input.parent();

    // Value ++
    $input.val($input.val() + 1);

    // Set the total count
    var val1 = +$parent.find('.val1').val();
    var val2 = +$parent.find('.val2').val();
    $parent.find('.count').val(val1 + val2);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about it, and sure I'll use under the same click event :)

Answer (score 2):

Got it working for you!
Use `$(this).parent().find();`

```js
$(function() {
 $('.click').on('click', function() {
  $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) + 1);
 });
 $('.click').click(function() {
  var val1 = + $(this).parent().find('.val1').val();
  var val2 = + $(this).parent().find('.val2').val();
  $(this).parent().find('.count').val(val1+val2);
 });
});
```

```css
.cont {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>First</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" class="count" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val1" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val2" value="0">
</div>

<h1>Second</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" class="count" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val1" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val2" value="0">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Here is the Solution for You:

```js
$(function() {
 $('.click').on('click', function() {
  $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) + 1);
 });
 $('.val1').click(function() {
  var val1 = +$(this).val();
  var val2 = +$($(this).siblings('.val2')).val();
  $($(this).siblings('.count')).val(val1+val2);
 });
   $('.val2').click(function() {
  var val1 = +$($(this).siblings('.val1')).val();
  var val2 = +$(this).val();
  $($(this).siblings('.count')).val(val1+val2);
 });
});
```

```css
.cont {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>First</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" class="count" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val1" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val2" value="0">
</div>

<h1>Second</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" class="count" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val1" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="click val2" value="0">
</div>
```